# vb.net error - Value of type 'Char' cannot be converted to 'Date'

Tags: vb.net

Still a noob at this so please be patient. 
Short version of my problem is I have a monthcalendar that pics a range of dates and adds them to label

```
Dim iStart as DateTime = MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDatestring
Dim iEnd as DateTime = MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.End.ToShortDatestring
Dim iCount as DateTime = iStart

While iCount <= iEnd
    iCount = iCount.AddDays(1)
    Lable1.Text = Label1.Text & iCount & vbNewLine
End With
```

Now that works perfectly. But this is part of individual records I want to add to my database. So was thinking of doing a For Each loop but getting the above mentioned error - Value of type 'Char' cannot be converted to 'Date' 
This is the beginning of the code

```
For Each iCount in label1.text    'This is where the error comes up
```

Please help

Comment: `For Each iCount in label1.text` is iterating *characters* in a string.  If you added a range of dates, they are no longer dates but a string of characters.  what are you really trying to do?

Comment: I want to add Each date that is selected and listed in the label as a new record in the database

Comment: If you need to extract them from the calendar save them to a `List(of Date)` so they remain dates (hopefully the db column is date as well).  Use the Label to show the user if you want, but UI controls make terrible program variables.

Comment: The only reason it shows up in a label when selected is for the user to double check that is the dates they want to use. Can you give me an example code of saving them as List(of Date) or a link to somewhere where I can learn more please

Comment: Is there a way of converting the string dates back to date format from the label? Like Cstr or CDate?

Comment: Why convert them only to convert them back? Use the label for the user, use date variables in the code.  [`List(Of T)` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean now. Don't pass it to string to return it to Date value. IS there any chance of showing me how the List(of T) works please? Like I said I am still learning

Comment: It is worse than that if you put several dates into a label, they are no longer several dates but one long string.  you'd have to parse them out first, then convert them one by one.  Spend 15 mins at the link I gave to MSDN, `List(Of T)` is one of the most valuable and useful things you could learn this week.  Thousands of examples here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have put them in using a common deliminator "vbNewLine', try using `Split` to retrieve them, though you would be better off using a List(of T) like Plutonix states in the first place.

This is an example using a console application that I used to test, so the UI elements are not present and were replaced with the equivalent variables.

Using `Split`

```
Sub Main()
    Dim iStart As DateTime = New DateTime(2014, 1, 1)
    Dim iEnd As DateTime = New DateTime(2014, 1, 15)
    Dim iCount As DateTime = iStart
    Dim LabelText As String
    Dim temp()

    While iCount <= iEnd
        iCount = iCount.AddDays(1)
        LabelText = LabelText & iCount & vbNewLine
    End While
    temp = LabelText.Split(vbNewLine) 'This seperates the single string back to individual entrys
    For Each s As String In temp
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(s)) 'Add to DataBase here.
    Next

End Sub
```

Using `List(of DateTime)` This is a lot easier with out having to reconvert.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim iStart As DateTime = New DateTime(2014, 1, 1)
    Dim iEnd As DateTime = New DateTime(2014, 1, 15)
    Dim iCount As DateTime = iStart
    Dim LabelText As String
    Dim tempDate As List(Of DateTime) = New List(Of DateTime)

    While iCount <= iEnd
        iCount = iCount.AddDays(1)
        tempDate.Add(iCount)  'Just add it here no conversion necessary
        LabelText = LabelText & iCount & vbNewLine
    End While

    For Each d As Date In tempDate
        Console.WriteLine(d) 'Add to Database here using Console.WriteLine as example
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Mark thank you for that but can you explain how to pass that then through a For Each loop to add those individual dates to the database? Unless I need to add it in another way

Comment: I am  presuming you mean the second example, you would do the same as I did with the Array in the first example. Will edit

Answer (score 1):

You can get this down to one (long) line of code:

```
Dim Days() As DateTime = Enumerable.Range(0, (MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.End.Date - MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Date).Days).Select(Function(i) MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.AddDays(i)).ToArray()
```

Break it up just a bit for readability:

```
Dim start As DateTime = MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Date
Dim stop As DateTime = MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.End.Date
Dim Days() As DateTime = Enumerable.Range(0, (stop - start).Days).
                          Select(Function(i) start.AddDays(i)).ToArray()
```

And then build your label string from the `Days()` array you already have, rather than building the label first and reconstructing the array later.

```
Lable1.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, Days)
```